# If $f(x)=g(x)f(h(x))$ with $g$ and $h$ known, can I obtain $f$?

Tags: calculus, functional-equations

EDIT-giving context: I was trying to find an explicit expression for a probability distribution using the Chapman-Kolmogorov equation. After using a saddle point approximation I reached an expression of the type $f(x)=g(x)f(h(x))$ being $f(x)$ the probability distribution in which I am interested and g(x) and h(x) two known non-linear functions (and well behaved). Since I am not used to work with this kind of recurrent equation, I was curious about a rather general question.

Say that there exists an unknown function $f$ that fulfills
$\begin{equation}
f(x)=g(x)f(h(x) 
\end{equation}$
and $\int dx f(x)=1$
with $g$ and $h$ being two known non-linear and well-behaved functions. Can the above equation be used to determine $f$? How?

Comment: Feels like too general of a question -- $f(x) \equiv 0$ works well :) otherwise, it would depend on $g$ and $h$ I am sure. What have you tried? In what context are you encountering the problem?

Comment: @gt6989b Thanks! I edited the question in order to add some context and specify that $f$ has to fulfill a constraint: it has to be normalized to 1.

Answer (score 4):

The equation is linear in $f$, so the answer can never be unique unless it's identically $0$ (which is always a solution).

An example where the only solution is $0$ is $h(x) = x$, $g(x) = 2$.

In general, $\mathbb R$ is partitioned into orbits under the map $h$: $x$ and $y$ are in the same orbit if $h^n(x) = h^m(y)$ for some positive integers $n$ and $m$ (where $h^n$ means $h$ iterated $n$ times).  On each orbit, $f$ is determined up to a multiplicative constant.  On a periodic (or eventually periodic) orbit, $f$ may be forced to be $0$.  There are no constraints linking different orbits.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I edited my original question in order to add an extra constraint that is in my problem: $f$ has to be normalized to 1, so I cannot use the solution f=0. I don't understand the argument based on the orbits. In particular, the statement  "$x$ and $y$ are in the same orbit...". Are $x$ and $y$ points of $\mathbb R$?

Comment: Yes, assuming these are functions on $\mathbb R$.